# brining together flex and blazeDS

Tags: java, flash, apache-flex, tomcat, blazeds

I'm new to all this stuff, and I'm starting a flex+blazeds project. First I coded some server classes, and modified xmls (in WEB-INF). Now I want to test it with client. There (in Flash Builder) it's needed to specify path to folder where server lives. The problem is that I cannot find it. In the same time `http://localhost:8400/MyAppServer/` is found in browser. What am I not understanding?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information on the configuration, I don't think anyone can help you.

If you are using **BlazeDS Turnkey**, there are examples there in both Java and Flex you can check.

If not, I really encourage you do start with Turnkey before trying to build your own BlazeDS application from scratch:

Go here and click on **Turnkey**, it has everything you need to start easily. 
https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=lc_blazeds

Hope that helps,
Cheers

Comment: Yes, I downloaded turnkey and used `blazeds.war`, however I cannot catch where app is compiled

Comment: Please read this: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/articles/blazeds_testdrive.html

Comment: Thank you! Right now I'm copying files to `tomcat/webapps` manually. Will make an ant script for that in future.